# Remove local lmod modules or update local lmod module list on HPC cluster

Tags: module, lua, hpc, lmod

I am working on a HPC cluster. I successfully created my local openmpi_gpu module (compiled with intel17.2 and cuda 8.0). What I did is that storing a cuda_17.2.lua file in the directory

```
${HOME}/modulefiles/Core/openmpi_gpu/
```

And after

```
module use $HOME/modulefiles/Core
```

I can see the new module "openmpi_gpu/cuda_17.2" by typing `module avail`.

Now, I intend to delete this module and replace it by a new openmpi compiled with intel 17.2 without cuda/8.0. So I `rm -rf openmpi_gpu` to remove the source file of openmpi_gpu, and recompile an openmpi just with intel 17.2. Then I remove the directory `${HOME}/modulefiles/Core/openmpi_gpu/`, and create a new directory `${HOME}/modulefiles/Core/openmpi_intel/` to store the new .lua file `local_17.2.lua`.

However, now I tried `module avail` but can still see the old module "openmpi_gpu/cuda_17.2", and cannot see the new module "openmpi/local_17.2".

I doubt that I should not delete the module just by removing the source file, or I should do something to update the module list. Anyway, does anyone has any idea about this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lmod uses a [cache](http://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/125_personal_spider_cache.html) so you are probably just seeing the cache and it has not been updated. Run the following command to reset it:

```
rm -rf    ~/.lmod.d/.cache
```

Alternatively, you can use the `--ignore_cache` option:

```
module --ignore_cache avail
```